# Xdebug PhpStorm breakpoint doesn't break

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a Docker container and I add Xdebug to it. In my DockerFile I add

```
&& pecl install xdebug-3.1.3 \
&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
&& echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >>  /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

in docker-compose:

```yaml
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

I've configured the CLI Interpreter in PhpStorm and Xdebug is correctly detected.

Now, if I add a breakpoint, my script doesn't stop. But if I add `xdebug_break()` my script will stop.

How to make it work with PhpStorm breakpoint ?

Moreover I was forced to install Xdebug in Chrome. It seems to me that I did not need this extension before, just to listen or not for PHP Debug Connections in PhpStorm.

there is xDebug config
[image: xdebug config 1]

[image: xdebug config 2]

Comment: What's your actual/live Xdebug config? You can see it by using `xdebug_info()`. Do it in the same way you are trying to debug (a web page or a CLI).

Comment: The thing is: by default Xdebug needs to see some trigger / "debug me" flag -- only then it will try to debug it. Xdebug helper for Chrome does just that -- it sets Xdebug cookie that Xdebug sees as such a "debug me" indicator. I suggest you use it (works well for me). But if you wish -- add `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` and Xdebug will try to debug **every single script** regardless of the "debug me" flag.

Comment: I edited my post with xDebug config
Yes for start_with_request is same thing that "Break at first line in php scripts" no ?

Comment: *"is same thing that "Break at first line in php scripts" no" NO. What that option does it tells PhpStorm to stop (make a breakpoint kind of behaviour) when the IDE will have an incoming debug connection. But it cannot do anything when Xdebug does not make that connection (does not try to debug the script)...

Comment: But yes, for CLI scripts that PhpStorm can run ("PHP Script" type of Run/Debug Configuration) the IDE sets all needed Xdebug params in the command line (so it can pass "debug me" param there). But it cannot do anything when you debugging a web page (as PHP is launched by a web server). Sure, there are "PHP Web page" type of Run/Debug config and a few more that can add such Xdebug param as a GET/POST parameter, but still -- you need to initiate that request from within PhpStorm and some requests can only be done live in a browser (JS interaction etc).

Comment: That's why you better use that Xdebug browser extension (or use [Bookmarklets](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/)) to set the Xdebug cookie (or pass GET/POST param into the URL). This allows to execute some pages normally (e.g. start the checkout process in your shop) and only trigger debugging on form submission or specific AJAX request for example. But at the end of the day it's up to you on what is the most convenient way of triggering the breakpoint/telling Xdebug to initiate the debug session.

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation @LazyOne but I use the Xdebug browser extension and if I don't put `xdebug_break();` on my code the PHPStorm's breakpoint doesn't work (if I don't use the extension, the `xdebug_break();` doesn't work)

Comment: Sorry, your last comment does not make much sense to me. I do not see how extension is needed if you are using `xdebug_break()` anyway. What that function does it tells Xdebug to try to debug this file even if the debug session is not active yet. You may need to enable Xdebug log and see if it tries to establish a debug session or not. If it does not then Xdebug possibly does not see the "debug me" flag (cookie or query param). Right now I may only suggest to check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html

Comment: Okay I will try to explain myself.
I add a breakpoint in my Controller.
I checked Break at first line.
Those two things never change.

Now if I refresh my page without the chrome extension, nothing happens
If I enabled the chrome extension and refresh my page, Xdebug show me the index.php (because break at first line) but I never get to my breakpoint on my controller.
And if I add `xdebug_break()` in my controller, one line before my breakpoint and refresh page, Xdebug show me the index.php, and when I resume, I can debug my controller

Comment: And I try the link you post but nothing change

Comment: Sadly this description does not help me. I need to see/feel it myself (know the exact setup and what is used) to have ideas on what may be going wrong. Right now it will be like guessing on the coffee mud. You def need to have Xdebug log to confirm that debug session is attempted.

Comment: I suggest you make a simple PHP test file (one instruction per line) and try to debug it instead. Does it work? If yes -- add an extra code (a class/include file) and debug that one. You may spot the pattern. Right now I may only say that I can debug my Laravel (and custom framework) controllers with no issues at all (when it does not work then I'm doing my user error or PC restart sorts it out).

Comment: I think it's a problem of path mapping, does that seem possible to you? I'm new on Docker and WSL, I have Linux system before and everything was good without any problems

Comment: Yes, that's possible. On `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Servers` you have to specify how to map remote file system to a local one for debugger to know what file to display/edit. Path mapping is also used when setting up the breakpoint. Once again: Xdebug log will show what file Xdebug uses and where the IDE sets the breakpoints (so you can compare if the path used matches the expected one).

Comment: But I have to specify the mapping for each file? or can i set it globally? I try to add the logs, I added this in my docker file: `&& echo "xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log" >>  /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \ && echo "xdebug.log_level=10" >>  /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \` and this in dockercomposer :   `- /tmp/xdebug:/tmp/xdebug` but after a refresh, in tmp I have an empty folder named xdebug

Comment: Folder mapping works just fine. Usually just having the project root folder is enough. *"but after a refresh, in tmp I have an empty folder named xdebug"* Your log file is `/tmp/xdebug.log`. This empty `/tmp/xdebug` comes from docker-compose file. NOTE, on some systems `tmp` folders get "private" per process (so the real path can be `/tmp/blablablabla/xdebug.log` -- check Xdebug docs -- https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#log

Comment: Finally everything finally works but I don't really understand why. However, I can't find the log file. I looked in my wsl folder in tmp but I can't find. I may be looking in the wrong place

Comment: @Cohchi can you post the solution as an answer? Thanks